# Open modal form(with different URL) without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, modal-dialog

Is there any way to open a modal form without refreshing the page but changing the url? I want my form to popup on the same page but mine is refreshing, so there is no sense to be modal... I am working with symfony and i put a different route in SecurityController for my login.view which extends the base.view.

**index.view**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <ul class="rotateButtons">
        <li class="rotateButton"><a href="{{ path('security_login') }}" class="round login">Login<span class="round">If you already have an account.</span></a></li>
        <li class="rotateButton"><a href="{{ path('user_register') }}" class="round register">Register<span class="round">If you don't have an account. </span></a></li>
        <li class="rotateButton"><a href="{{ path('print_all_songs') }}" class="round catalog">Catalog<span class="round">Take a look.</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**login.view**

```
<!--Login form-->
<div id="id01" class="modal">

    <form class="modal-content animate" action="{{ path('musicshare_index') }}" method="post" >
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="closeModalFunction()" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="{{ asset('pictures/remixLogo2.jpg') }}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            <p class="formText">Login</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="_username" required>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="_password" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"/>
            <button type="submit">Log In</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="buttons">

    <ul class="rotateButtons">
        <li class="rotateButton"><a href="#" class="round login" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Login<span class="round">If you already have an account.</span></a></li>
        <li class="rotateButton"><a href="#" class="round register" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">Register<span class="round">If you don't have an account. </span></a></li>
        <li class="rotateButton"><a href="#" class="round catalog">Catalog<span class="round">Take a look.</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**login.view - javascript**

```
<script>
    function closeModalFunction() {
        document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';
        window.history.replaceState( {} , '/' );
        window.history.back();

    }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
</script>
```

**SecurityController - login function**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/login", name="security_login")
 */
public function login()
{
    return $this->render("security/login.html.twig");
}
```

[**Home page - picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgauy.png)

[**Loaded login form - picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CftFj.png)

Comment: What does `without refreshing the page but changing the url` mean?  Like them physically typing in a new URL or them clicking on a link that changes the address but doesn't load a new page?

Comment: clicking on a button that changes the address but doesn't load a new page  like pop-up a login form which have to be sudbmit

Comment: I added a pictures of my form to get the idea

Comment: Changing the url in the url bar of the clients browser sounds like a bad idea. You will mislead the users that way. You can make a separate login-page that have the modal standard open. (Just add the class "open" to the modal). Let the form in the modal on the other page(s) submit to the login page which handles the form.